# Special characters with in php - javascript - ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have simple comment script that enable to add / edit / remove comments. I have a problem with special characters.

If var currentMessage contains ' or " then the code breaks.

I save the comments in the db as follows :

$Message = clean_data($_POST["txtmessage"]); 
Then do a typical mysqli_query save ....

```
function clean_data($input) {
    $input = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($input,",")));
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    $input = stripslashes($input);
    $input = stripslashes($input);
    $input = htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_IGNORE, 'utf-8');
    $input = trim($input);
    $sqllink = new mysqli(MySQL_Host, MySQL_UserName, MySQL_Password, MySQL_Database);
    $input = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqllink, $input);
    no_magic_quotes($input);
$input = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $input);
    $input = str_replace("&", "&#38;", $input);
    $input = str_replace('"', "&#34;", $input);
    $input = strip_tags($input);
    return $input;
}
```

The data saved in MySQL is as follows : `let&#38;#39;s do it !`

My edit button is like this:

```
<button id="BtnEdit_<?php echo $r_c['CommentID']; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" onClick="showEditBox(this,<?php echo $r_c['CommentID']; ?>)" name="edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> <? echo _("To Edit"); ?></button>
```

My message displayed like this:

```
<div class="message-content"><? echo $r_c['Message']; ?></div>
```

If I show the special characters in php echo, then the javascript doesn't work. If I remove all ' or "" then it's ok. But it is not practical.

```
function showEditBox(editobj,id) {
    $('#BtnEdit_'+ id).hide();
    $('#frmAdd').show();

    var currentMessage = $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html();
    var editMarkUp = '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="txtmessage" id="txtmessage_'+id+'" value="'+currentMessage+'"><br><div class="btn-group pull-left"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" name="ok" onClick="callCrudAction(\'edit\','+id+')"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> <? echo _("Save"); ?></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" name="cancel" onClick="cancelEdit(\''+currentMessage+'\','+id+')"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <? echo _("Cancel"); ?></button></div>';
    $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").html(editMarkUp);
}
```

The data is displayed as follows : let\'s do it ! (it would be better if it would be - let's do it !)

The edit button doesn't even work if there is ' in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not need all that cleaning with calls to `htmlentities`, `strip_tags`, `stripslashes`, `htmlspecialchars`, `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `no_magic_quotes`. Although you haven't included the code where you insert the data, it shows that you are not inserting it with a prepared statement. And that is exactly what you should go for.

It could look like this:

Writing to the DB in PHP:

```
$message = $_POST["txtmessage"]; 
$sqllink = new mysqli(MySQL_Host, MySQL_UserName, MySQL_Password, MySQL_Database);
$stmt = $sqllink->prepare("INSERT INTO messages(message) VALUES(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $message);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The HTML generation *should* make sure to use HTML entities where necessary, notably for the ampersand. So call `htmlspecialchars` here:

```
<div class="message-content"><? echo htmlspecialchars($r_c['Message']); ?></div>
```

The JavaScript button click handler should not take the `html` from the message, but the `text`. Also, don't set the `value` of the `input` in a HTML snippet; instead assign the value with `val()`:

```
function showEditBox(editobj, id) {
    $('#BtnEdit_'+ id).hide();
    $('#frmAdd').show();

    // Use text():
    var currentMessage = $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").text();
    // Instead of building HTML with string concatenation, build nodes with jQuery.
    // That way you don't have the problem of escaping/encoding
    var nodes = [
        $("<input>").addClass("form-control input-sm").attr({
            type: "text", name: "txtmessage", id: "txtmessage_"+id
        }).val(currentMessage), // <-- here is where the value is set
        $("<br>"),
        $("<div>").addClass("btn-group pull-left").append(
            $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-xs btn-success").attr({ name: "ok" }).append(
                $("<i>").addClass("fas fa-check"),
                "<? echo _("Save"); ?>"
            ).click(callCrudAction.bind(null, 'edit', id))
        ),
        "\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0", // non-breaking spaces
        $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-xs btn-default").attr({ name: "cancel" }).append(
            $("<i>").addClass("fas fa-times"),
            "<? echo _("Cancel"); ?>"
        ).click(cancelEdit.bind(null, currentMessage, id))
    ];
    $("#message_" + id + " .message-content").empty().append(nodes);
}
```

I did not change the HTML, but instead of producing non-breaking spaces you should add margin to the buttons with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you used prepared statements you wouldn't have to corrupt your data like this. And even so, you've stacked up so many conflicting layers of data corruption-- oops I mean *"sanitization"*-- I would be surprised if this is the first or only problem you're having.

```
// Validate that the data is the type/size you expect, but don't modify it
$message = basicValidation($_POST["txtmessage"]);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?)')
$stmt->bind_param("s", $message);
$stmt->execute();
```

This protects you from SQL injection and ensures that your data is inserted *exactly* as specified without having to do any corrupting nonsense with HTML entities, stripslashes, or other things that should only be applied to *output*.

Retrieving data for *display* is when you should apply transformations to make it safe to include in HTML or whatever *other* format you might use. You wouldn't want to inject a bunch of nonsense HTML entities into a PDF document, would you?

```
$message = mysqli_nonsense();
?><div>
<p><?= htmlentities($message) ?></p>
</div>
```

This protects you from JavaScript injection.

So much simpler, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you propose, but I am using a code that was not started from me. I cannot now change everything. Is there a way to easily accept special characters from this output without redoing everything ?